# kali's airmon-ng doesn't list out existing interfaces on mac

Tags: wifi, osx, kali-linux

I am using Kali Linux on my mac inside of parallel desktop. When I type `airmon-ng` no interface gets listed. May be I am missing the right drivers for kali. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use airmon-ng if you have a seperate USB WiFi Adapter! This is essential, without one it's not possible to use airmon-ng.